# viewing my comments that were deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

A while back I had a long discussion in comments
probably with somebody on the answer to this
 one  [Hard Disk:S.M.A.R.T. Stas BAD, Back up and replace](https://superuser.com/questions/356545/hard-disks-m-a-r-t-stas-bad-back-up-and-replace)

but they were deleted because comments aren't for that, chat is..  This was before a chat link would pop up.

I thought my comments would be nicely stored and had a few links there, only to find the comments gone.

Is it possible to view the comments.

And why not as a small courtesy, when comments are removed, can't the system post the comments to you, so you at least have a copy of what you commented and they're not gone.

Answer (score 1):

I checked that post and there are no deleted comments on the question or the answer. If you can find which post it was, a moderator can retrieve the deleted comments for you.

There's little value in automatically preserving comments because most of the time when they are removed, it is because they are off-topic or low quality, and comments generally have a low signal-to-noise ratio. The bother of making them available isn't worth what little value that would provide.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to link to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85469/147926) on MSO as it's a pretty nice summary of why access to deleted comments is a bit... meh...

Comment: This might just stem from a difference in industry practice and standards (I work in food safety), but IMO record retention and traceability isn't an insignificant value?  `...most of the time when they are removed, it is because they are off-topic or low quality, and comments generally have a low signal-to-noise ratio...`  You've said it yourself that this is a *generalization*, and the the criterion for evaluation is still susceptible to error or bias.  At the very least, I don't see how an automated courtesy ping would be unreasonable, in case the post actually *was* valuable to the poster.